# Software Foundations (lf): proving leb_plus_exists and plus_leb_exists

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I've been working through Volume 1 of Software Foundations, and I can't get past a pair of optional questions in Logic.v. Anyone have any idea what to do?

Theorem leb_plus_exists : forall n m, n <=? m = true -> exists x, m = n+x.
Proof.
Admitted.

Theorem plus_exists_leb : forall n m, (exists x, m = n+x) -> n <=? m = true.
Proof.
(* FILL IN HERE *) Admitted.

I simple cannot get past intros in the first question. I am completely stumped on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that solutions to exercises in Software Foundations, especially volume 1: Logical Foundations, are *not to be published*.

So, here is a hint: do `induction n` *before* you do `intros m`, which keeps all statements *general* in `m`.

Or, not necessary here, but if you do all `intros` first, then you need `generalize dependent m`: see [generalize dependent](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.generalize-dependent).